# Angular 2 RxJS filter to new observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm pretty new to RxJS (using 5.1.1) and trying to understand it in my Angular 2 applciation using angular-redux/store.

I've got a store set up and working to get different parts of my state in my application.

Now, I'm trying to get AppParts that have the loaded property set to true:

my state:

```
export interface IAppState extends IRootState{
  theme: Theme;
  config: IConfig;
  mainSubTitle: string;
  appParts: AppPart[];
}
```

the select:

```
@select(state => state.app.appParts) appParts$: Observable<AppPart>;
```

now, I'm trying to get a filtered array from this observable:

```
loadedAppParts = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.appParts$.filter(a => a.loaded).subscribe(a => { console.log(a); this.loadedAppParts.push(a); });
}
```

However, this returns an empty array. I'd like to be able to use the async pipe to get the 'loadedAppParts' if possible too, so I've also tried doing the following:

```
loadedAppParts: Observable<AppPart> = new Observable<AppPart>();
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadedAppParts = this.appParts$.filter(a => a.loaded);
}
```

So, how can I get a filtered array or observable from my Observable state?

Forgot to add my Rootstate:

```
export interface IRootState { };
```

and my initial state:

```
export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  theme: THEMES.LightGreyBlue,
  config: <IConfig>{
    data: {
      apiUrl: ''
    },
    general: {
      appName: 'Default name',
      appShortName: 'default'
    }
  },
  mainSubTitle: 'Default',
  appParts: [new AppPart('core', true)]
};
```

And the template part that displays the JSON to debug (for the array example):

`{{ appParts$ | async | json }} {{ loadedAppParts | json }}`

When using the Observable: 
`{{ appParts$ | async | json }} {{ loadedAppParts | async | json }}`

This returns: `[ { "name": "core", "loaded": true } ] null`

Comment: Can you show the template part as well? This error happens when you try to convert two objects that reference to each other into JSON which I don't think is what you want to do.

Comment: when using the array: {{ appParts$ | async | json }} {{ loadedAppParts | json }} ; when using the Observable: {{ appParts$ | async | json }} {{ loadedAppParts | async | json }}; the last one returns  [ { "name": "core", "loaded": true } ] null

Comment: From the output it looks like the `appParts$` is emitting an array of `AppPart` objects so correct type would be `Observable<AppPart[]>`. If you try to flatten the emissions with `this.loadedAppParts = this.appParts$.mergeAll().filter(a => a.loaded);` does it help?

Comment: Hi Martin, great stuff, this indeed fixed it! Could you perhaps create an answer with a small explanation why mergeAll() has to be used here, I've never used that operator before. I'll accept it as an answer then! :) Thanks

Comment: 1 thing, this seems to return an object, not an array. So if there are 2 AppParts with the loaded property set to true, it only returns the last result. Can I get it so that loadedAppParts can be an array of AppParts? I guess the mergeAll() makes it an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSON output you can see it looks as follows:

```
[ { "name": "core", "loaded": true } ] null
```

So the `appParts$` is in fact emitting arrays of objects (`Observable<AppPart[]>`) instead of just objects (`Observable<AppPart>`).

Then when you use `this.appParts$.filter(a => a.loaded)` you're trying to filter the items by `.loaded` property that doesn't exist on an Array object so it's always empty.

In fact you want to filter the objects inside that array. In other words you need to flatten the array into single items. This means we want to turn this:

```
[ { "name": "core", "loaded": true }, { "name": "core", "loaded": true }, { "name": "core", "loaded": true } ]
```

into this:

```
{ "name": "core", "loaded": true }
{ "name": "core", "loaded": true }
{ "name": "core", "loaded": true }
```

That's what the `mergeAll()` operator can do. Using `mergeAll()` is in this case the same as using `merge(array => Observable.from(array))`.

```
this.appParts$.mergeAll().filter(a => a.loaded);
```

Now when you chain it with `.filter(a => a.loaded)` you're filtering the `AppPart` objects.

Note that when using `async` filter it subscribes to the Observable and renders always **only the last item emitted** from the source.

You can use `toArray()` to again collect the filtered items into an array:

```
this.appParts$.mergeAll().filter(a => a.loaded).toArray();
```

This has one important consequence. The `toArray()` operator emits only after the source Observable has completed (but maybe this isn't an issue in your use-case).

Alternatively if you want to just collect all items you could use also `scan()` operator that emits the collection on every emission from the source (however this operator might cause multiple view updates).

```
this.appParts$.mergeAll().filter(a => a.loaded).scan((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(item);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've seemed to fix it with this code too: this.loadedAppParts = this.appParts$.map(appParts => appParts.filter(a => a.loaded)); this returns an Observable<AppPart[]> just like the appParts$.